# Semantic Security in Formal Security Proofs

Tags: provable-security, semantic-security

I have a trivial question, and I hope someone can help me.

I am reading several papers on formal security proofs based on the indistinguishably game. Specifically, the adversary is challenged in an experiment to distinguish between the real key and a random generated string. We flip a coin, say $b$, and if $b=0$ the output of the oracle query is the real key and if $b=1$, the output of the oracle query is a random string. The adversary wins the game upon guessing the correct $b$.

The question is, some papers write the advantage of the adversary as:
$$\mathsf{ADV}_\mathcal{A} = |2 \cdot \Pr[b=b']-1 |$$
or
$$\mathsf{ADV}_\mathcal{A} = | 2\cdot \Pr[\text{sucess}] -1 |$$

while others write it as

$$\mathsf{ADV}_\mathcal{A} = \Pr[\mathcal{A}\text{ wins}] - 1/2$$

Is there any difference between the two expressions?

Comment: I tried to make the notation more readable, please check that I did not misinterpret anything. The first equation is probably the result of a typo, there's einer a $2\cdot$ or a$/2$ missing. Otherwise the advatage would always be $\leq 0$. Could you check your source?

Comment: It is written this way, please look at page 71 of the following https://link.springer.com/content/pdf/10.1007/978-3-540-30580-4_6.pdf

Comment: Also, in security proof, you are suppose to prove that the Adversary, A, has negligible advantage to win the indistinguishably game

Comment: Literally none of the notations from your question appear on that page. The closest one is the second one. But I was asking about the first.

Comment: Here is a link of an IEEE paper, published in 2018. Please look at page 830 Definition 7 (semantic security) . https://www.dropbox.com/s/1ujpyv3x53p1cuh/07589015.pdf?dl=0

Comment: sorry, my mistake I have missed the factor 2. I just edited the question.